# Inserting a Page Break between charts

Tags: excel, page-break, vba

I have an Excel worksheet on which I am organizing a bunch of charts. The charts stack vertically, on upon the other (with some spacing and labels in between for organization). The charts don't fit on a single printed page, so I have to insert page breaks at the right places. The number of charts and the size of each chart can change, so I don't know exactly where to put the page break until run time.

I do know that I want to print two charts on each page, however. So, what I want to do is to put a page break either after the second chart or before the third chart (either way). But it looks to me like page breaks are always associated with a row, not with an object (like a chart).

Is there a way to either:

1) associate a page break with an object (e.g. `ActiveSheet.HPageBreaks.Add before:=ActiveSheet.ChartObject("myChart3")`)

2) determine which row the top of the object sits in. If I could determine this, then I can easily place the page break at that row. For example, I can get `ActiveSheet.ChartObject("myChart").Top`, but I don't know what row this corresponds to. I tried setting every row to a height of 1 and then doing a one-to-one correspondence, but it doesn't match up.

Comment: Perhaps `ActiveSheet.ChartObject("myChart").Parent.BottomRightCell` (taken from http://www.pcreview.co.uk/forums/re-finding-last-row-chart-t947465.html).

Comment: `before:=ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("myChart3").TopLeftCell`

Comment: Thanks to you both. Great suggestions!